# SQLAlchemy: find child objects in a relationship with NULL parent

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask

I have a class which has a parent-child relationship:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
  __tablename__ = "parent_table"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  children = relationship("Child", backref="parent")
  def all_children(self):
    pass # I want self.children + "Child where parent_id = NULL"

class Child(Base):
  __tablename__ = "child_table"
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent_table.id')
```

I would like to add a function to my parent which returns the parent's children in the relationship, and also all Child objects which have their parent_id column set to NULL.

The whole situation is a bit more complex because the classes are actually a case of joined table inheritance like this: [table_per_related](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/_modules/examples/generic_associations/table_per_related.html), but I don't even know where to start so would probably be able to figure it out from there.

(The whole thing must be usable in the context of a web service via Flask)

**Edit:** Update. This is a minimal implementation of what I really wanted to do, as I can't quite manage to translate the first answer into something that works in this context:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base, declared_attr
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class BaseCols:
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String)

  def __repr__(self):
    return "<{}: {} - {}>".format(self.__class__.__name__, self.id, self.name)

  @declared_attr
  def __tablename__(cls):
    return cls.__name__.lower()

Base = declarative_base(cls=BaseCols)

class Child(BaseCols):
  pass

class HasChild:
  @declared_attr
  def children(cls):
    cls.Child = type("{}Child".format(cls.__name__),
                     (Child, Base,),
                     dict(
                          __tablename__="{}_children".format(cls.__tablename__),
                          parent_id=Column(Integer, ForeignKey("{}.id".format(cls.__tablename__))),
                          parent=relationship(cls)
                     )
                    )
    return relationship(cls.Child)

  def all_children(self):
    pass

class Foo(Base, HasChild):
  __tablename__ = 'foo'
  __mapper_args__ = {'concrete': True}

class Bar(Base, HasChild):
  __tablename__ = 'bar'
  __mapper_args__ = {'concrete': True}


if __name__ == "__main__":
  engine = create_engine('sqlite://', echo=True)
  Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

  session = Session(engine)

  session.add_all([
    Foo(
      name = "Foo the first!",
      children = [
        Foo.Child(name="Heir Apparent."),
        Foo.Child(name="Spare.")
      ]
    ),
    Foo(
      name = "Foo the second...",
      children = [
        Foo.Child(name="Some child."),
      ]
    ),
    Bar(
      name = "Bar the first!",
      children = [
        Bar.Child(name="Bar's.")
      ]
    ),
    Foo.Child(name="whoops"),
  ])

  session.commit()

  foo1 = session.query(Foo).first()
  print(foo1)
  print(foo1.children)
  print(foo1.all_children(session))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class Child(Base):
    # ...

class Parent(Base):
    # ...
    def all_children(self):
        return Child.query.filter((Child.parent_id == self.id) | (Child.parent_id == None)).all()
```

Note that I moved the `Child` class above `Parent`, so that it can be referenced in `all_children()`.

**Update**: Here is the implementation for the code you added to your question:

```
    def all_children(self, session):
        cls = self.__class__.Child
        return session.query(cls).filter((cls.parent_id == self.id) |
            (cls.parent_id == None)).all()
```

Comment: Yes! I still have a few details to figure out with the table_per_related setup, but will post back if I run into other difficulties.

Since I didn't come across it in my searches, where is the Class.query syntax documented?

Comment: The `class.query` syntax is from Flask-SQLAlchemy. If you are using plain SQLAlchemy the equivalent syntax is `session.query(Class)`. See http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html

Comment: Sorry, I still haven't been able to make this work in my context. I've expanded my original question with a minimal working example (if you have python3 and sqlalchemy to hand). Could you have a look at this please?

Comment: great answer @miguel , but it can't bring a child value, for example, I have 5 records in `parent_table` and the second record of parent has a record in `child_table` (e.g parent_id: 2) but another parent's record hasn't record in `child_table`, then how i can grab all data including child records even the other is not?